# How to access an object's key using a state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I have an object and I want to access to key of the object using state.

This is the object:

```
cosnt data = {
    name: "this is title",
    description: "this is the description text"
}
```

This is the state:

```
const [filter, setFilter] = useState("description")
```

I can get the info using this line of code:

```
const pieceOfData = data.description // expected console.log = "this is the description text", so it works as expected!
```

I want to access using a state but I don't know what kind of a syntax I have to use:

```
const pieceOfData = data.filter
const pieceOfData = data.[filter]
const pieceOfData = data[filter]
const pieceOfData = data(filter)
//they are not giving the information
```

Comment: `data[filter]` should work !

Comment: As @NidhiDadiya stated. Maybe your `filter` state has a different value when you are trying to use it on `data`

Comment: `data["description"]` works. `data[filter]` not works. and gives an error saying: "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ title: string; description: string}"

Comment: @yusufcode, I think you are using typescript and getting this error. You can try like `data[filter as keyof typeof data]` .

Comment: @ManirajMurugan can I target only one key of data? e.g. `data.description`. Because in my real data object, there is an id key and it's a number. I'm using `toLowerCase()` method, so I'm getting an error like "Property 'toLowerCase' does not exist on type 'string | number'." I just want to target a single key of the object. What kind of a typescript code I have to write?

Comment: @yusufcode, You can try with the help of `typeof` and something like this,  `typeof data[filter as keyof typeof data] === 'string' ? `data[filter as keyof typeof data].toLowerCase` : null`

Comment: @ManirajMurugan unfortunately it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Bracket Notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) to access an object's key using a state.

```
const [filter, setFilter] = useState("description");

const data = {
    name: "this is title",
    description: "this is the description text"
}

setFilter('description');

console.log(data[filter]);
```

Answer (score 1):

`data[filter]` should have worked but I am using Typescript. So @ManirajMurugan helped me to solve the problem.

This is the correct answer:

```
data[filter as keyof typeof data]
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope it helps !

```js
const data = {
    name: "this is title",
    description: "this is the description text"
}

console.log(data);

const filter = 'name';

console.log(data[filter]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Using `data["key"]`

```
const data = {
        name: "this is title",
        description: "this is the description text"
}

const [filter, setFilter] = useState("description")

const pieceOfData = data[filter]

console.log(pieceOfData);
```

Answer (score -1):

data[filter] should work also make sure proper syntax used for keyword. currently you defined object with wrong keyword.